# How to read large (~20 GB) xml file in R?

Tags: r, large-data

I want to read data from large xml file (20 GB) and manipulate them. I tired to use "xmlParse()" but it gave me memory issue before loading. Is there any efficient way to do this?

My data dump looks like this,

```
<tags>                                                                                                    
    <row Id="106929" TagName="moto-360" Count="1"/>
    <row Id="106930" TagName="n1ql" Count="1"/>
    <row Id="106931" TagName="fable" Count="1" ExcerptPostId="25824355" WikiPostId="25824354"/>
    <row Id="106932" TagName="deeplearning4j" Count="1"/>
    <row Id="106933" TagName="pystache" Count="1"/>
    <row Id="106934" TagName="jitter" Count="1"/>
    <row Id="106935" TagName="klein-mvc" Count="1"/>
</tags>
```

Comment: do you need the whole document tree in the workspace at once? otherwise you could read line after line

Comment: No need to load whole data at once. I may read line by line and process them? Or I may load the data as chunks and then process them. I would appreciate if you can give any suggestions.

Comment: you could use the function readLines and set n to the number of lines you want to read. it should also be possible to use a SAX parser (the package you use provides it). I can add an example later (don't have R on this machine). maybe you can explain more what you want todo with your file, than it will be easier to provide a meaningful example.

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643580/combine-values-in-huge-xml-files also helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In XML package the `xmlEventParse` function implements SAX (reading XML and calling your function handlers). If your XML is simple enough (repeating elements inside one root element), you can use `branches` parameter to define function(s) for every element.

Example:

```
MedlineCitation = function(x, ...) {
  #This is a "branch" function
  #x is a XML node - everything inside element <MedlineCitation>
  # find element <ArticleTitle> inside and print it:
  ns <- getNodeSet(x,path = "//ArticleTitle")
  value <- xmlValue(ns[[1]])
  print(value)
}
```

Call XML parsing:

```
xmlEventParse(
  file = "http://www.nlm.nih.gov/databases/dtd/medsamp2015.xml", 
  handlers = NULL, 
  branches = list(MedlineCitation = MedlineCitation)
)
```

### Solution with closure:

Like in Martin Morgan, [Storing-specific-xml-node-values-with-rs-xmleventparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536754/storing-specific-xml-node-values-with-rs-xmleventparse):

```
branchFunction <- function() {
  store <- new.env() 
  func <- function(x, ...) {
    ns <- getNodeSet(x, path = "//ArticleTitle")
    value <- xmlValue(ns[[1]])
    print(value)
    # if storing something ... 
    # store[[some_key]] <- some_value
  }
  getStore <- function() { as.list(store) }
  list(MedlineCitation = func, getStore=getStore)
}

myfunctions <- branchFunction()

xmlEventParse(
  file = "medsamp2015.xml", 
  handlers = NULL, 
  branches = myfunctions
)

#to see what is inside
myfunctions$getStore()
```

Comment: This works fine for me!. Is it possible to solve this problem using Hadoop in   R? Let say i want to count each TagName.

Comment: I am doing something similar as you mentioned. The problems is that It slows down with time. It was very quick to print out things at the beginning. I tried using "rm(list -ls())", but doesn't help even.

Comment: Updated with a solution from M. Morgan (with a closure).

Comment: @Karthick did you ever figure out a way to do this without the memory slow-down? I'm experiencing the same thing.

Comment: @Karthick did you ever figure out a way to do this without the memory slow-down? I'm experiencing the same thing