# Read large xml into Dataframe r

Tags: r, xml, large-data

I want to read my xml into a dataframe in r. My intial Datafile is 14 GB so my initial try to read the file didn't work out:

```
f=xmlParse("Final.xml")
df=xmlToDataFrame(f)
r=xmlRoot(f)
```

The problem is that it is always running out of memory....

I've also seen the question:

[How to read large (~20 GB) xml file in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28667856/how-to-read-large-20-gb-xml-file-in-r)

I tried to use the approach from Martin Morgan, which i didn't 100% understood but tried to apply to my dataset.

```
libary(XML)
branchFunction <- function() {
store <- new.env() 
func <- function(x, ...) {
 ns <- getNodeSet(x, path = "//Sentiment")
value <- xmlValue(ns[[1]])
print(value)
# if storing something ... 
# store[[some_key]] <- some_value
}
getStore <- function() { as.List(store) }
list(ROW = func, getStore=getStore)
}

myfunctions <- branchFunction()

xmlEventParse(
file = "Inputfile.xml", 
handlers = NULL, 
branches = myfunctions
))

myfunctions$getStore()
```

I would have to do that for every Column separately and the structure i'm getting from the ouptput is not useful.

The Structure from my Data looks like:

```
<ROWSET>
<ROW>
    <Field1>21706</Field1>
    <PostId>19203</PostId>
    <ThreadId>38</ThreadId>
    <UserId>1397</UserId>
    <TimeStamp>1407351854</TimeStamp>
    <Upvotes>0</Upvotes>
    <Downvotes>0</Downvotes>
    <Flagged>f</Flagged>
    <Approved>t</Approved>
    <Deleted>f</Deleted>
    <Replies>0</Replies>
    <ReplyTo>egergeg</ReplyTo>
    <Content>dsfg</Content>
<Sentiment>Neutral</Sentiment>
</ROW>
<ROW>
    <Field1>217</Field1>
    <PostId>1903</PostId>
    <ThreadId>8</ThreadId>
    <UserId>197</UserId>
    <TimeStamp>1407351854</TimeStamp>
    <Upvotes>0</Upvotes>
    <Downvotes>0</Downvotes>
    <Flagged>f</Flagged>
    <Approved>t</Approved>
    <Deleted>f</Deleted>
    <Replies>0</Replies>
    <ReplyTo>sdrwer</ReplyTo>
    <Content>wer</Content>
<Sentiment>Neutral</Sentiment>
</ROW>
<ROW>
    <Field1>21306</Field1>
    <PostId>19103</PostId>
    <ThreadId>78</ThreadId>
    <UserId>13497</UserId>
    <TimeStamp>1407321854</TimeStamp>
    <Upvotes>0</Upvotes>
    <Downvotes>0</Downvotes>
    <Flagged>f</Flagged>
    <Approved>t</Approved>
    <Deleted>f</Deleted>
    <Replies>0</Replies>
    <ReplyTo>tzjtj</ReplyTo>
    <Content>rtgr</Content>
<Sentiment>Neutral</Sentiment>
</ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

Comment: You should provide a *complete* minimal example of your XML, otherwise it's really hard for others to be able to test their suggested solution.

Comment: I expanded the example xml, it seems that a part of the xml got cut out while i posted it.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, since you deal with big datasets, you should indeed use `xmlEventParse` which relies on the SAX, *ie* the *Simple API for XML*.The advantage of this vs. using `xmlParse` is that you will not load the XML tree in R (which can cause memory leaks if data is really big...).

I don't have a big dataset in hands, so i cannot test in *real* conditions but you can try this code snippet:

```
xmlDoc <- "Final.xml"
result <- NULL

#function to use with xmlEventParse
row.sax = function() {
    ROW = function(node){
            children <- xmlChildren(node)
            children[which(names(children) == "text")] <- NULL
            result <<- rbind(result, sapply(children,xmlValue))
          }
    branches <- list(ROW = ROW)
    return(branches)
}

#call the xmlEventParse
xmlEventParse(xmlDoc, handlers = list(), branches = row.sax(),
              saxVersion = 2, trim = FALSE)

#and here is your data.frame
result <- as.data.frame(result, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Let me know how it runs!

Comment: I tried to run the code on a 4 GB dataset, The Problem is that the xmlEventParse creates only an empty list. It worked well on a small dataset but wasn't able to create the Dataframe on the big Dataset. @eblondel

Comment: the xmlEventParse returns an empty list indeed, but you should not care about what ``xmlEventParse`` returns (you can embedd the ``xmlEventParse`` with ``invisible()``. With the function ``row.sax``, we feed the ``result`` object. The use of ``xmlEventParse`` prevents from having to duplicate the memory used in R (the XML tree + the resulting ``data.frame``). The code i provided allows you to have only the ``data.frame``. Do you obtain an error with the big dataset? to see if i can help you

Comment: On a small xml the xmlEventParse creates a Large Matrix, the problem is that the object created by xmlEventParse creates a NULL(empty) Value instead of a Large Matrix. Furthermore there is no Error or Warning occuring when the xmlEventParse finishes. Also the process would be too fast, it should take at least 20 min and stops/finishes after 5 minutes. @eblondel