# Huge XML-Parsing/converting using R or RDotnet

Tags: r, xml, csv, r.net

I have XML file of 780GB (yes yes, indeed, 5GB pcap file which was converted to XML).
The name of the XML file is tmp.xml.

I am trying to commit this operation in R-Studio:

```
require("XML")

xmlfile<<-xmlRoot(xmlParse("tmp.xml"))
```

When I am trying to do it with R I get errors (memory allocation failure, R session aborted etc).
Is there any benefit to use RDotnet instead of the regular R?
Is there any way to use R to do this?
Do you know another strong tool to convert this huge xml to csv or easier format?

Thank you!

Comment: You maybe able to use the `xmlEventParse` function to read and parse as it descends the tree. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643580/combine-values-in-huge-xml-files/22646164#22646164 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28667856/how-to-read-large-20-gb-xml-file-in-r